# Exposing the configurable properties of a plug in to a GUI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, plugins

Referring back to this post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9874735/1462656

I was thinking doing something similar, make all my plug ins expose the configurable proerties using an interface that contains a dictionary of property names and value pairs.

However my problem is how do you group properties together, or how do you have separate collection of properties that may each represent different settings.

For example say I have an application that user can plug in different processors.  Each processor will behave entirely different from each other.

Processor 1 has these settings

```
<Target location="1" action="dosomething" option="4">
<Target location="2" action="dosomething" option="4">
...and so on
```

This I could probably represent using a collection of Dictionaries
Maybe something like

```
List<Dictionary<string,string>>
```

But say I have Processor 2 with entirely different settings

```
<Key persist="true">
    <ValueFrom location="1" />
    <ValueFrom location="4" />
    <ValueFrom location="7" />
</Key>
```

I don't see how in the original post I link above I can represent all configurable items in a simple Dictionary.  Unless I represent each sublevel by a different key?  Would it still work?

Also if you did have a hierarchy of settings, how do you tell the GUI about this so it can create the appropriate controls to display it?

Answer (score 1):

When I did something similar recently, the most important question (I think) that I asked myself was, **does the host application** (the GUI in your case) **need access to view or modify the plugin settings?**

In my case the answer was, no, and so I could forget all about the details of what data or how each plugin stores it, and simply provide a container for it to be stored. The plugin's properties are retrieved `As Object`, serialized, stored, or whatever else I need to do with them, then sent back to the plugin upon the next instantiation. It is entirely up to the plugin to decide which properties to store, how to store them (variable, class, etc..), and to subsequently do the conversion from `Object` when receiving its properties.

How you allow the user to change those properties is a factor of how 'pretty' you want things to be, but in my situation I opted for a PropertyGrid (mine was a WinForms project). This way the plugin could expose each property exactly how it chooses, complete with descriptions, help text, and TypeConverters. Granted that it's not the most attractive interface, but in terms of prepackaged 'completeness' it is quite powerful.

Comment: Regarding the last sentence of your first paragraph - this is the part I'm unclear how to proceed on.  If the plug in is storing it's settings in a specialized class structure what do I convert this to (for all plug ins) so the GUI will know what to display?  One possibility I was considering is XML - I could serialize the plug in settings class to XML and the GUI would read the settings from all my plug ins as XML  - displaying them in the appropriate hierarchy.